# How do I recreate the width of columns in a JTable after changing the ColumnModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

So I have a JTable with 24 columns.  When the table is initialized, I make set the widths of the columns and the user interface looks great.  No complaints.  The user can click a button to only see 4 of the columns.  I change the array of columns on the table model and then call

```
firetablestructurechanged()
```

which then removes all of the column widths I established (but now only shows the 4 columns, the intended behavior).  When I try re-defining the column widths, nothing seems to change.

This is what I use to set column widths

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
for (int i = 1; i < columnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
columnModel.getColumn(i).setMinWidth(50);
columnModel.getColumn(i).setMaxWidth(50);
}
```

How do I get the columns to resize after  firetablestructurechanged() gets called?

Comment: One approach is to provide a customised `TableColumnModel` which can "hide" and "show" columns. [This example](http://www.stephenkelvin.de/XTableColumnModel/) is a little out of date, but the basic premise is sound...

Comment: Just a suggestion, could you use [JXTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22417960/1795530) to allow users toggle columns? I think your problem will be easily solved and user experience highly improved not only for this feature but others added in that library (i.e.: the ability to search in a table), not to mention that columns still can be resizable and you don't have to waste time dealing with fixed sizes.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10089138/524900) shows how to hide columns of a JTable. No need for a custom `ColumnTableModel`. All you need to do is remove the columns from the default `TableColumnModel`, this does _not_ remove them from the `TableModel`, thus you shouldn't need to call `fireTableStructureChanged()`.